# NativeScript Sidekick

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

When I load Sidekick I get an error due to the user-agent being used, which is Chrome version 58 which is 14 version old. I cannot run this on our corporate network due to our security policy.

Is there any settings I can change so I can load Sidekick successfully.

Cheers

Mike

Comment: I don't think there is, but if you raise a issue at [sidekick-feedback](https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues), they might be able to give you some directions on this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try there